# Quais propriedades da arquitetura e do sistema operacional permitem um ataque de buffer overflow?

Tags: gerenciamento-de-memória, memória, buffer-overflow

Ataques do tipo ***buffer overflow*** (estouro ou transbordamento de dados) ocorre quando, ao escrever em um espaço de memória, um programa ultrapassa os limites do buffer e escreve em uma área de memória adjacente.

Eu gostaria de saber que características, do ponto de vista da arquitetura e do sistema operacional, permitem esse tipo de ataque?

Answer (score 2):

É uma pergunta meio ampla, mas vamos lá.

O maior risco é utilizar uma linguagem de programação de baixo nível, tipo C, porque nela você é obrigado a utilizar ponteiros para manipular strings e buffers. Cedo ou tarde o programador comete um erro e abre uma brecha.

Usar uma linguagem de nível mais alto diminui o risco. É claro que o próprio compilador ou interpretador da linguagem pode ter bugs, porque provavelmente ele é escrito em C, mas via de regra este tipo de código passa por mais escrutínio, e o risco está concentrado numa área menor.

Se usar C é obrigatório, o ideal é utilizar uma biblioteca para strings, por exemplo o venerável QMail usava uma biblioteca do próprio autor. Novamente, a biblioteca pode ter bugs mas você concentra o risco num código relativamente pequeno em vez de espalhar por todo o código de cada programa.

O sistema operacional pode ajudar muito a mitigar os riscos de buffer overflow, com recursos no estilo:

- randomização do layout de memória de cada processo: evita que os mesmos elementos ocupem sempre o mesmo endereço na memória virtual. Os ataques tipo "script kiddie" presumem um endereço fixo.
- Bit NX (exige suporte da CPU): evita que código na pilha seja executável, o que inviabiliza algumas modalidades de ataque de buffer overflow;

O compilador pode colaborar, detectando alguns tipos de buffer overflow mediante verificação da pilha. Acho que todo compilador moderno incorporou já as idéias do "StackGuard", um fork do GCC popular nos anos 90.

A biblioteca C (libc) colabora checando erros como duplo free(), que não são buffer overflow mas também são vetores de ataque.

Tanto no compilador como na libc há proteções ainda mais fortes, mas que causam quebra de performance, aí o desenvolvedor pode optar por elas se a troca for vantajosa. Muitas vezes herda-se código C de má qualidade, não é possível reescrever e o jeito é defender-se.

Em resumo, todo sistema operacional moderno tem proteções em diversos níveis, e a situação é bem melhor que nos anos 90. Mas a melhor profilaxia é certamente evitar linguagem de baixo nível desnecessariamente.

Answer (score 1):

Ao compilar um programa em C a característica de o que é cada byte de memoria se perde. O tamanho de cada array simplesmente é removido por performance e não é possível determinar onde começa e acaba cada objeto na memoria. Dessa forma onde quer que o programa escreva, assume-se que ele está certo.

O sistema operacional não mantém um controle tão granulado de memória a ponto de ser capaz de detectar por conta própria estouros de buffers. A memória virtual de cada processo é dividida em **páginas** (usualmente 4 KiB ou 32 KiB). Cada página pode ser legível, escritível, ou executável. O código do programa, por exemplo, é legível e executável, mas não pode ser modificado. Sendo assim o sistema saberá se você tentar escrever em uma página que não existe ou não pode ser modificada e mandará um sinal ao processo (que geralmente vai abortar em um crash).

Ou seja, a margem de erro do sistema é de uma página. E se a página adjacente for alocada e escritível, nada acontecerá. Como a maioria dos ataques se baseia em escrever dados em uma memoria escritível, o sistema nada fará para o proteger.

A esse nível, uma técnica que pode ser útil é marcar páginas que você não planeja escrever como *read-only*. Mas essa é uma proteção bastante falha já que causará um crash em caso de ataque.

O que você deve fazer é tratar desse se proteger desses ataques no seu próprio programa. Não é papel do sistema operacional.

Se você está programando em uma linguagem de alto nível, sem usar ponteiros, então você muito provavelmente está seguro. Para muitas linguagens é impossível conseguir escrever um código suceptível a esse ataque.

Mas se você está em uma linguagem mais baixa (como o C, onde o lema é *confie no programador, ele sabe o que faz*), todo cuidado é pouco. Nesses casos nunca é possível ter completa certeza de que o código está livre de oportunidades de ataque. Uma boa solução é usar o [**Address Sanitizer**](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/). Ative no GCC ou Clang com a opção `-fsanitize=address`.